# Woocommerce Order Export

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv, orders

I'm using

> WooCommerce Simply Order Export (Plugin)

in Woocommerce Website. Using this Plugin when I export orders which are under specific Order Statuses(e.g. Processing, Completed etc), Plugin give me an option to select date range and no. of columns(e.g. Product Name, Product Quantity, Variation etc.), But the Problem is:

If Order-1 contains 1 product with some quantity(e.g. Fanta (Quantity = 4)), Similarly Order-2 contains the same product(e.g. Fanta (Quantity = 2))

So I need to update the Plugin in which I create a button to export Accumulated Quantity of Products(Sum of same item across all Orders), I need 2 Columns in Exported CSV(Product Name, Accumulated Quantity), Kindly help me in this updation.

TIA

Comment: It seems you want to customize plugin , did you contact to plugin developer? They can help you more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Yeah I need to customize plugin, I contacted plugin developer but they aren't helping in this matter, they are saying that we do not customize plugins according to customer needs, customer have to do it by themselves... Please help me in this regard, I'm new in WP development.

Comment: I see , then you should post this question here : wordpress.stackexchange.com , I hope you will get help quickly.

Comment: I believe this plugin is what you need: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-sales-report-for-woocommerce/

Comment: @Philip Dude You are awesome :D It Worked! Put your comment in answer, I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin that you can use (with the functionality you need) is this one:
[Product Sales Report for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-sales-report-for-woocommerce/)

If you want to get a custom report, you can use the `WC_Admin_Report()` class and the `get_order_report_data()` to build your custom query.